# Синхронизация потоков

Tags: java

Пытаюсь синхронизировать потоки, но не очень выходит. Какого вывода я ожидаю:

Поток №1
Поток №2
Поток №3

Поток №1
Поток №2
Поток №3

Поток №1
Поток №2
Поток №3

Но, увы, никак не догоню..использую приостановку потока.

```
    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {
        SomeThing st = new SomeThing();
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(st);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(st);
        Thread thread3 = new Thread(st);

        thread1.setName("Поток №1");
        thread2.setName("Поток №2");
        thread3.setName("Поток №3");


        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread3.start();
    }

}

class SomeThing implements Runnable 
{
    public void run()
    {
        int sec = 500;
        for(int i = 0;i<3;i++)
        {
            try {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                Thread.sleep(sec);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Объясните, как лучше поступить в данном случае.

Comment: Я правильно понял, необходимо потоки выполнить друг за другом, т.е. 2-й ждет завершение 1-го, а 3-й 2-го?

Comment: @EugeneKirin нет, немного не так. Там ниже дан замечательный ответ :)

Comment: А как вывести результат чтобы именно как автор хочет:
Поток №1 Поток №2 Поток №3
Поток №1 Поток №2 Поток №3
а не так:
Поток №1 Поток №2 Поток №3
Поток №1 Поток №2 Поток №3
Поток №1 Поток №2 Поток №3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка 1: вы запускаете 1 поток 3 раза, это сделать невозможно поток одноразовый. Если нужно повторить операцию, надо создать новый объект Runnable

Ошибка 2: У вас по факту нет никакой синхронизации, да и зачем если нет разделяемого ресурса.

Если вы хотите, чтобы потоки работали по порядку, то нужен какой-то индикатор. Он должен будет подсказать потокам, чья сейчас очередь.

в простом варианте без пулов и executor'ов предложу такой вариант

логика:

- Присвоить каждому потоку номер
- Создать общую переменную, которая будет определять очередность

код:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        SomeThing.setMaxTask(3);
        SomeThing st1 = new SomeThing(1);
        SomeThing st2 = new SomeThing(2);
        SomeThing st3 = new SomeThing(3);
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(st1);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(st2);
        Thread thread3 = new Thread(st3);


        thread1.setName("Поток №1");
        thread2.setName("Поток №2");
        thread3.setName("Поток №3");


        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread3.start();
    }

    private static class SomeThing implements Runnable{
        private static int maxTask;
        private int number;
        private static volatile Integer query = 1;

        public SomeThing(int number) {
            this.number = number;
        }

        public void run(){
            for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
                try {

                    while (!query.equals(number))
                        Thread.sleep(100);

                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    synchronized (query) {
                        if (query.equals(maxTask)) {
                            query = 1;
                        }
                        else {
                            query++;
                        }
                    }


                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

        public static void setMaxTask(int maxTaskIn) {
            maxTask = maxTaskIn;
        }
    }
}
```

Он ужасен, непрактичен и бесполезен, но это лучшее что смог сделать "на коленке", то что полностью выполняет вашу задачу.

Как я и описал в начале. Мы используем переменную `query` в качестве индикатора очереди. Пока номерок в очереди не равен номеру потока, поток спит. Когда номерок очереди совпадает с номером потока, поток выходит из цикла while и выполняет итерацию цикла for. В начале новой итерации он снова утыкается в while и так по кругу 3 раза.

Так же здесь жестко закодировано количество потоков в очереди `macTask`, если задать значение больше чем потоков, то код зависнет.

Ключевое слово volatile используется, чтобы значение  `query` всегда было актуальным, а не бралось из кеша.

Если честно я мог где-то ошибиться и буду рад если вы найдете тут баг =) я не магистр многопоточности.

Comment: Лучше вместо Thread.sleep использовать wait, поскольку у вас потоки простаивают достаточно большое количество времени

Comment: @Roman Danilov полностью согласен, но было 5 утра, а wait кидал ошибку, не хватило времени написать нормально.

Comment: Прекрасно, невероятно! Спасибо огромное! Да, на счёт синхронизации я погорячился, она тут не к месту. Впервые столкнулся с установкой очередности потоков, было трудно сообразить что-то..еще раз спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
 /*
             используем lock(); , unlock();
 */
package threads;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

/**
 *
 * @author vvm
 */
public class MyThread extends Thread {

    static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private String strVoice;

    private void setVoice(String str) {
        this.strVoice = str;
    }

    MyThread(String str) {
        this.setVoice(str);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (;;) { // бесконечные цикл
            System.out.println(this.strVoice);
            try {
                MyThread.sleep(1000);// чтобы спорили медленнее
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                // Logger.getLogger(ChickenVoice.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            lock.lock();
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Тестируем:

```
/*
 тестируем MyThread.java
 */
package threads;

/**
 *
 * @author vvm
 */
public class TestMyThreads {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyThread th0 = new MyThread("поток 0");
        MyThread th1 = new MyThread("поток 1");
        MyThread th2 = new MyThread("поток 2");
        MyThread th3 = new MyThread("поток 3");


        th0.start();
        th1.start();
        th2.start();
        th3.start();
    }
}
```

Вывод:
поток 0
поток 2
поток 1
поток 3
поток 0
поток 2
поток 1
поток 3

Они будут выполняться последовательно. Но неизвестно, в каком порядке они начнут работать.